# What is a Django QuerySet?

Tags: django, django-queryset

When I do this,

```
>>> b = Blog.objects.all()
>>> b
```

I get this:

```
>>>[<Blog: Blog Title>,<Blog: Blog Tile>]
```

When I query what type `b` is,

```
>>> type(b)
```

I get this:

```
>>> <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
```

What does this mean? Is it a data type like `dict`, `list`, etc?

An example of how I can build data structure like a `QuerySet` will be appreciated.

I would want to know how Django builds that `QuerySet` (the gory details).

Comment: You can look at the source code of Django to see the gory details. Other than that, a QuerySet is just an object like many others which happens to behave like a list sometimes.

Comment: For what it is: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/ For how it works, as already mentioned, have a look at the source code.

Comment: Here is where QuerySet is defined in Django: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Yes, it's just another type](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/), built [like every other type](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: Link-only answer? That should be a big no-no…

Answer (score 69):

A [django queryset](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) is like its name says, basically a collection of (sql) queries, in your example above `print(b.query)` will show you the sql query generated from your django `filter` calls.

Since querysets are [lazy](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), the database query isn't done immediately, but only when needed - when the queryset is *evaluated*. This happens for example if you call its `__str__` method when you print it, if you would call `list()` on it, or, what happens mostly, you iterate over it (`for post in b..`). This lazyness should save you from doing unnecessary queries and also allows you to chain querysets and filters for example (you can filter a queryset as often as you want to).

Answer (score 12):

A QuerySet represents a collection of objects from your database. It can have zero, one or many filters. Filters narrow down the query results based on the given parameters. In SQL terms, a QuerySet equates to a SELECT statement, and a filter is a limiting clause such as WHERE or LIMIT.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/

Answer (score 2):

A QuerySet is a list of objects of a given model, QuerySet allow you to read data from database