# Nested foreign key serializer in django not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Part of `models.py`:

```
class FoodCuisine(models.Model):
    cuisine = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cuisine


class CuisineTypes(models.Model):
    cuisine_types = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    cuisine = models.ForeignKey(FoodCuisine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cuisine_types

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('cuisine_types',)


class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=192)
    veg = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    cuisine_type = models.ForeignKey(CuisineTypes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def _cuisine(self):
        return self.cuisine_type.cuisine
```

`serializers.py`:

```
class FoodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Food
        fields = ('name', 'veg')


class CuisineTypesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foods = FoodSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='food_set')
    class Meta:
        model = CuisineTypes
        fields = ('cuisine_types', 'foods')


class FoodCuisineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cuisine_type = CuisineTypesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='cuisinetypes_set')
    class Meta:
        model = FoodCuisine
        fields = ('cuisine', 'cuisine_type')
```

I want the `FoodCuisineSerializer` to return a nested list which will have all the food items categorized by their respective cuisine types and their cuisines.

The categorization is straight forward, having a list of cuisines in the first level, cuisine types in the second and food items in the third level.

Problem is that `FoodCuisineSerializer` only returns the first level only *i.e.* only the list of cuisines are shown. But I want the full nested list of food items as given in the previous paragraph.

Edit 1:

https://pastebin.com/dmVbyS0G is what I got from Django shell.

Edit 2:

If I write

```
>>> y = FoodCuisineSerializer(FoodCuisine.objects.get(id=2))
>>> y.cuisine_type
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'FoodCuisineSerializer' object has no attribute 'cuisine_type'
```

Why do I get the above error?

Edit 3:

Got the `source` in the right place but now I am getting:

```
>>> y = FoodCuisineSerializer(FoodCuisine.objects.get(id=2))
>>> y.data # I get the desired result having OrderedDict
>>> y = FoodCuisineSerializer(FoodCuisine.objects.all())
>>> y.data
[Error]
```

[Error]: https://pastebin.com/0DW28qv4 Whats next?

Comment: You may have to look into using the `depth` option. You can read more about that [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization)

Comment: `depth` isn't helping. I just tried it out. How can I debug this further?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/dmVbyS0G is what I got from django shell.

Comment: @ComproPrasad Added an answer. Please do try it

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to work. @JPG

Comment: have you got any error?

Comment: Check edits in question. No errors from django. But `cuisine_type` isn't defined as shown in the Edit 2.

Comment: @ComproPrasad  Add the full error traceback pls

Comment: @ComproPrasad I've updated the answer. It was a typo. Change **`cuisine_types_set`** to **`cuisinetypes_set`**

Comment: Please see the 3rd edit.

Comment: @ComproPrasad you should pass many=True in serializer....see my updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set **`source='cuisinetypes_set'`** while serializeing the queryset as,

```
class FoodCuisineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cuisine_type = CuisineTypesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='cuisinetypes_set')

    class Meta:
        model = FoodCuisine
        fields = ('cuisine', 'cuisine_type')
```

**Reference**
1. [reverse relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)
2. [**`source`** in DRF-Serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)

**UPDATE 1**
Since `FoodCuisine.objects.all()` is a [**`QuerySet`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681202/what-is-a-django-queryset) (`list` type object), you should pass **`many=True`** in serializer, as

```
y = FoodCuisineSerializer(FoodCuisine.objects.all(), many=True)
```

Comment: @Compro Prasad Updated the answer