# Query two tables in Django on currently authenticated user

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Im trying to query 2 tables in my django model - but having some issues formulating how to write the syntax.

**models.py**

```
class T(models.Model): 
    emailVerified = models.EmailField(max_length=50) 
    dNm = models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True)
    FKToUser = models.ForeignKey('auth.user', default=None, on_delete=models.PROTECT)  

class TSF(models.Model):
    httpResponse = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(3)])
    FKToT = models.ForeignKey('T', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

In regular (pseudo) sql I'm trying to do something like:

```
SELECT dNm
FROM T, TSF
WHERE T.id=TSF.FKToT
AND T.FKToUser=<<THE CURRENTLY SIGNED IN USER>>
```

I'm just having some issues formulating how to write this in django orm.

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: This is documented: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: Also, a Django Model `ForeignKey` field resolves to a model instance, so `T.FKToUser` should really be named `T.user` (the Model layer abstracts the relationship so you don't have to manually fetch the related model instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this,

```
TSF.objects.filter(FKToT__FKToUser=request.user)
```

This will return a **`TSF`** [**`Queryset`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681202/what-is-a-django-queryset) object that related to the currently logged-in user.
You could use [**`values()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) to retrive specific fields from the **`QuerySet`** if you want.

---

#### Update -1

> what is this notation: FKToT__FKToUser doing?

The **`__`** (double underscore) is the ***field lookup*** notation in Django (You could read more here, [**Django Field lookup--Django Doc**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups))

But, here the **`__`** is something ***lookup through the relation***, [**Lookups that span relationships- Django Doc**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)  which results in **SQL JOIN**

Comment: Question: what is this notation: `FKToT__FKToUser` doing?

Comment: @Jshee what about reading the doc ? (link provided in another comment).

Comment: @Jshee I've updated the answer with some more information. Hope it will enlighten you.