# Getting error : AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'usertype' in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on login api, when i tried to run this command   
`user_profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user_id=user.id).values('usertype')`
It gives me this error : `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'usertype'` but in console i checked i am getting its queryset  `<QuerySet [{'usertype': 2}]>` but not able to fetch the value from it, can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ? here is my signin function of it

```
class Login(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request):
        username = request.data.get("username")
        password = request.data.get("password")
        if username is None or password is None:
            return Response({'success': False, 'error': 'Please provide both username and password'},
                            status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        # return Response({'success': True, 'user': user},status=HTTP_200_OK)
        if not user:
            return Response({'success': False, 'error': 'Invalid Credentials'},
                            status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        access_token, refresh_token = utils.generate_tokens(user)


        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user_id=user.id).values('usertype')

        print(user_profile.usertype)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`user_profile`** is a [**`QuerySet`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681202/what-is-a-django-queryset) object, a **`list`** like iterable. If you want to access the **`usertype`**, you should either use array index or a loop

#### Method-1

```
print(user_profile[0]['usertype']) # this will print data from the first item
```

#### Method-2

```
for item in user_profile:
    print(item['usertype'])
```

Comment: It gives me this error now : AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'usertype'